# Android Studio 1.1.0 Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently running Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca. All of the projects I open have this error message when I start it up. What could be causing the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely a build.gradle file with a error in it.

Try to execute the gradle-wrapper directly via a terminal and look at the output, it should tell you whats wrong.

The gradle wrapper is in your root project file.
The following command builds your .apk:

`./gradlew assemble`

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in android studio with the generated R file, check in your activity if this is generating it, if it is rebuild the project and the errors should go away